# Improve visual clarity of super/subscripts in LaTeX

Tags: latex, r-markdown, visualization

I was wondering how to get my superscript/subscript variables to look more clean, as I have seen in publications. For example, I would like letters within a superscript closer together, to limit visual clutter on certain variables. A visual example of this is below:

Here is what my variables look like:
[image]

Versus what I have seen in a publication:
[image]

In the publication, the PH in the superscript is closer together. Any idea how to clean up these kind of variables that have a superscript and subscript index?

Here is my code (I use R Markdown to create my pdfs):

```
\frac{\rho{_N^{CN}}}{n{_N^{CN}}}
```

Comment: Try using a negative space `\!`

Comment: `\mathit` also has less spacing. Maybe is what they used in your example?

Comment: Thanks @IgnatiusReilly, I'll try both of those things!

Comment: the negative space makes it look infinitely better! If you make it an answer I can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In math mode, LaTeX uses a larger spacing to separate variables, since it assumes that *CN* should be understood not as "CN" but as "C by N". Sometimes this can be undesired either because you want to use an actual word or, as in your case, you may feel it doesn't look so good.

A couple of solutions could be, either to use negative spaces `\!`:

`\frac{\rho{_N^{C\!N}}}{n{_N^{C\!N}}}` : [image]

or to use `\mathit{}`, wich for capital letters is quite similar to normal math mode, but with shorter spacing:

`\frac{\rho{_N^{\mathit{CN}}}}{n{_N^{\mathit{CN}}}}` : [image]